# Взять случайные группы столбцов из датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть небольшой датайфрем в котором каждые 4 стобца сгруппированы между собой и относятся к одной сущности (это обозначается первой цифрой в названии столбцов).
Всего 60столбоц и 15 общностей: [данные](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jcdsrH5AK1BGZd-Ftf5BTtVr2aImYjISsWg-kfiV1Bg/edit?usp=sharing).

Мне необходимо случайным образом взять 5 таких общностей и составить из них датафрейм для дальнейшей работы. Эту процедуру я буду выполнять много раз, делать много всевозможных комбинаций.

Пока удалось придумать, как это сделать, только путем случайного вытаскивния строчек: для этого я транспонирую данные, выбираю случайным образом строки и транспонирую обратно:

```
df.T
df.sample(n=5)
df.T
```

Но придумать, как вытаскивать не 5 рандомных строк, а именно 5 общностей (5 групп по 4 строки, каждая из которых с одинаковым номером в первой цифре), пока не могу. Можете посоветовать что-нибудь, пожалуйста?

Надеюсь, суть вопроса нормально описана..

Comment: Эээ, ну можно же из `df.columns` делать `random.choices` и брать эти столбцы из `df` просто `df[random.choices(df.columns, k=5)]`как-то так. Хотя лучше из `Numpy` наверное `random.choice` взять, он более управляемый.

Comment: @CrazyElf я там понимаю. автору надо брать родственные группы столбцов, случайным образом пять разных _групп_

Comment: @strawdog Я в целом понял, но там группировка по первой цифре в названии столбца, соответственно будет просто не `df.columns`, а их подмножество выбранное

Comment: Хотя я возможно не до конца понял суть. Хорошо бы предоставить желаемые на выходе данные

Comment: Ага, добавлено на Лист 2 гугл-таблицы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы предложил создать мультиндекс сначала, чтобы удобнее было работать с группами колонок, а затем выбирать из групп случайные самплы:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
```

ваш df:

```
    1.1 1.6 1.8 1.10    2.7 2.4 2.11    2.1 3.6 3.3 ... 13.2    13.6    14.4    14.7    14.5    14.1    15.3    15.6    15.1    15.5
0   2   3   4   2   2   3   3   4   2   3   ... 3   3   2   3   4   2   2   3   3   3
1   4   3   3   0   4   2   3   4   4   4   ... 3   3   2   3   3   4   2   3   3   3
2   4   3   3   2   4   4   3   4   3   3   ... 3   4   2   3   3   4   4   3   3   4
3   3   2   4   3   1   4   3   4   4   3   ... 3   4   3   4   4   3   1   3   3   4
4   4   3   4   3   2   3   3   3   2   3   ... 4   3   2   3   3   4   2   1   4   3
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
278 4   3   2   3   4   2   3   4   4   1   ... 2   4   4   3   3   4   4   3   3   4
279 4   4   3   3   4   3   4   3   2   3   ... 3   4   4   3   3   2   4   3   3   4
280 4   3   3   4   2   3   3   4   2   3   ... 3   4   4   3   3   3   2   3   3   2
281 3   4   4   3   4   3   3   3   4   4   ... 3   3   4   3   4   3   4   3   4   3
282 3   3   4   3   4   2   4   3   3   3   ... 2   4   4   4   4   4   2   4   4   3
```

далее:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[i.split(".")[0] for i in df.columns], [i.split(".")[1] for i in df.columns]])
df[random.sample(df.columns.levels[1].tolist(), 5)]
```

получаем что-то типа такого:

```
    8          10           7           3           6         
     6  5  4  8  7  5  3  6  6  5  4  2  6  3  5  4  4  2  3  6
0    2  3  3  2  2  3  3  4  2  3  3  2  2  3  4  3  2  3  4  4
1    2  3  3  4  2  3  3  4  2  3  3  3  4  4  3  4  0  3  1  4
2    4  3  3  4  4  1  1  4  4  3  3  0  3  3  3  4  2  3  4  4
3    4  4  3  3  4  3  4  4  1  3  3  3  4  3  4  4  3  3  1  2
4    2  1  3  4  3  2  3  4  2  3  3  2  2  3  3  4  2  3  3  4
..  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..
278  4  3  4  4  4  3  3  4  4  4  4  3  4  1  4  4  3  3  3  4
279  2  2  3  4  4  4  3  4  4  3  4  3  2  3  3  4  4  4  3  4
280  4  3  3  2  4  3  3  4  2  1  3  3  2  3  3  4  4  3  3  4
281  4  2  4  4  4  4  4  3  4  2  3  3  4  4  3  4  3  3  2  3
282  4  3  3  4  4  3  4  4  4  4  3  1  3  3  4  4  4  3  4  4
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё получилось! Правда, если я ничего не путаю, там в нижней строке нулевой индекс должен быть: df[random.sample(df.columns.levels[0].tolist(), 5)]